# Assing dynamic IP to a task running with AWS Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am new to AWS, but actually i could not find something clear in the documentation.

I am attempting to run a scheduled task with in a ECS Cluster with Fargate. I wonder how is the IP assigned? Will it be always the same, and each time the scheduled task starts it gets a new IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your task is publicly accessible it will retrieve its IP address from the AWS public IP address pool for the region you sit in. At this moment there is no way to assign a static public IP address although there is a [issue](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/311) raised with Amazon.

For the private IP address, a random private IP address is taken from the pool of the available IP addresses in the subnet the container will be launched in.